# Controlling default values in view from model - EF CORE

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I've set the default for a Boolean in the model using both

```
    [DefaultValue(true)]
```

and

```
public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
```

and for good measure I've added

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<modelName>().Property(p => p.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
```

That all works nicely and my database table has the correct "Default value or binding".   In my Create view I want the default property to be used but can't find out how to use the model's default properties in the view. Using

```
<input asp-for="IsActive"  class="form-control" checked="checked"/>
```

works, but that's me hardcoding the `checked="checked"` value myself. How do I read the model's default value in the view?

Edited for requested code, the model is

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace securitytrials.Models {
    public class CaseType {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TheID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    }
}
```

the action method is the default generated by the template.

```
public IActionResult Create() {
    return View();
}
```

Didn't include them as there's not much there but the defaults.
The `DbContext.OnModelCreating` is just

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseType>().Property(p => p.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultValue` doesn't actually *do* anything. I can be utilized by code generators in certain situations, but largely in the context of your web application, it's completely meaningless. As the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) detail:

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

`HasDefaultValue` merely sets the `DEFAULT` for the column, so you may need that as well, if you want the actual table schema to reflect the default, but the only thing that really helps your code is:

```
public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
```

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. As there should be no issue with that alone in an input displaying that default value. In other words, the following code:

```
<input asp-for="IsActive" class="form-control" />
```

Will generate:

```
<input type="textbox" class="form-control" checked="checked" />
```

If it's not, then there's some issue with your model. Either you're confused on which class you've added the default value to, or something else in your code is changing that value before it hits your view. However, without more code to work with, like your action method, it's impossible to say.

Comment: I want it to do exactly what I said and what you've put, set the checkbox to "checked" when the model says it should be checked.
There's only one model, the action method is just the default one. I've added them to the original question

Comment: Do `return View(new CaseType());`